# Is $\frac{-1}{n}<0$ or must equality be allowed ($\frac{-1}{n}\leq 0$)?

Tags: inequality

Is this true

$$\dfrac{-1}{n}< 0 $$ for all n$\in \mathbb{N}$?

Or is it false and I have to write:

$$\dfrac{-1}{n}\leq 0$$ for all n$\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: The meaningfulness of these statements depend on whether $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ but most mathematicians would agree that $\infty \not \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that $\dfrac{-1}{n}< 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It is also true  $\dfrac{-1}{n}\le 0$ that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Moreover, since $\dfrac{-1}{n}$ is *never* zero, the statements are equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean with the equivalence of these statements? They are both true, but they are independent of any variables.